# NLog doesn't log to database when executor gets killed

Tags: nlog

I use NLog in an app that starts a worker executable, gets the results from the worker and then the worker gets killed or exits by itself.

This is the configuration I use:

```xml
  <nlog autoReload="true" throwExceptions="true" internalLogFile="c:\webapplogs\Nloglog.log" internalLogLevel="Warn" xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <variable name="datasource" value="Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=DEV_DB;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=****" />
    <variable name="logDirectory" value="C:\webapplogs\/logs" />
    <variable name="message_one_line" value="${replace:inner=${message}:searchFor=\\r\\n|\\r|\\n:replaceWith=\xB6:regex=true}" />
    <!--Pilcrow = "\xB6";-->
    <variable name="exception_one_line" value="${replace:inner=${exception:format=tostring}:searchFor=\\r\\n|\\r|\\n:replaceWith=\xB6:regex=true}" />
    <!--Pilcrow = "\xB6";-->
    <variable name="exception_and_message_with_level" value="${longdate} =&gt; (${uppercase:${level}}) | ${callsite} : ${message_one_line} | ${exception_one_line}" />
    <variable name="trace" value="${longdate} =&gt; ${message_one_line}" />
    <targets>
      <!-- https://github.com/nlog/NLog/wiki/File-target -->
      <target name="logfile" type="File" fileName="${logDirectory}/${shortdate}.${logger}.CmdLineWorker.Tracing.log" layout="${exception_and_message_with_level}" keepFileOpen="True" concurrentWrites="True" openFileCacheTimeout="30" />
      <target name="tracefile" type="File" fileName="${logDirectory}/${shortdate}.${logger}.log" layout="${trace}" keepFileOpen="True" concurrentWrites="True" openFileCacheTimeout="30" />
      <target name="console" type="Console" layout="${message}" />
      <target name="database" type="Database" connectionString="${datasource}" commandText="exec dbo.Error_Insert @********">
        <parameter name="@ErrDate" layout="${date:format=yyyy-MM-dd HH\:mm\:ss}" />
        <parameter name="@ErrUser" layout="CmdLineWorker" />
        <parameter name="@LogLevel" layout="${level}" />
        <parameter name="@ErrOrganization" layout="CmdLineWorker" />
        <parameter name="@ErrMessage" layout="${message}" />
        <parameter name="@ErrInnerException" layout="${exception:format=ToString}" />
        <parameter name="@ErrCallsite" layout="${callsite}" />
      </target>
    </targets>
    <rules>
      <logger name="*" minlevel="Trace" writeTo="logfile" />
      <logger name="*" minLevel="Error" writeTo="database" />
    </rules>
  </nlog>
```

In some situations, I kill the worker when something goes wrong.

When I kill the worker, logging (using the ERROR level) in the log file works great but the problem is that, most of the times, logging in the DB does not happen. I kill the executable after logging but it seems that it doesn't log to the DB directly, so I kill it before it tries to actually log the error.

So, with the config above, I get the desired error in the log file, but not in the DB, which is odd.

Is there a buffer for logging in the DB?

Is there a setting that can fix this problem?

Also, note that delaying to kill the worker is not a very good option in my case, so I would like to avoid it.

Comment: Make sure NOT to use `throwExceptions="true"` it is only for unit-testing. Have you checked the NLog `internalLogFile` ? Who is the one doing the database logging ? (worker-executable or main App)

Comment: @RolfKristensen The logging is done by the worker and it works only for file logs. For the DB it fails because the worker is killed. I have tried things like `LogManager.Flush(); LogManager.Shutdown(); Task.Delay(10000);`, but still it doesn't work reliably when it comes to logging in the DB. Not sure why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When exiting the program, you need to flush all the events:

```
NLog.LogManager.Shutdown(); // Flush and close down internal threads and timers
```

Writing to the database could take some more time than directly to file, so that could explain the differences.

See also: https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Tutorial

> **Remember to Flush**
>
> NLog will by default attempt to flush automatically at application shutdown. Microsoft Windows give .NET applications a limited amount of time to perform shutdown (usually 2 sec) before being terminated. If having a NLog configuration with NLog Targets that requires network-traffic (Http, Mail, Tcp), then it is a really good idea to perform a manual Flush/Shutdown independent on running on Linux/Windows.
>
> ```
> NLog.LogManager.Shutdown(); // Flush and close down internal threads and timers
> ```
>
> NET Application running on Mono/Linux are required to stop threads/timers before entering application shutdown phase. Failing to do this will cause unhandled exceptions and segmentation faults, and other unpredictable behavior.

Comment: Thanks. I have tried this: `LogManager.Flush(); LogManager.Shutdown(); Task.Delay(10000);` but when killing the worker it still doesn't log. Not sure what else I can try.

Comment: Hm... Probably now it is a timing issue with the parent application that makes it kill the worker too early, before the shutdown call.